# toolchain cc-compiler-x64_windows

Tags: bazel

```
ERROR: C:/users/pemgithub/_bazel_pemgithub/3mdmxsrc/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/BUILD:58:1: Target '@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:malloc' depends on toolchain '@local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-x64_windows', which cannot be found: no such target '@local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-x64_windows': target 'cc-compiler-x64_windows' not declared in package '' defined by C:/users/pemgithub/_bazel_pemgithub/3mdmxsrc/external/local_config_cc/BUILD.bazel'
ERROR: D:/pemcode/amd/gapid/cmd/gapir/cc/BUILD.bazel:34:1: Target '//cmd/gapir/cc:gapir_unstripped' depends on toolchain '@local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-x64_windows', which cannot be found: no such target '@local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-x64_windows': target 'cc-compiler-x64_windows' not declared in package '' defined by C:/users/pemgithub/_bazel_pemgithub/3mdmxsrc/external/local_config_cc/BUILD.bazel'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:pkg' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.897s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
    currently loading: @io_bazel_rules_go//go/private ... (3 packages)
    Fetching @com_github_golang_protobuf; Restarting.
```

I'm trying to build GAPID on Windows, https://github.com/google/gapid/blob/master/BUILDING.md

...

Update using bazel 0.26.0, I get a different error

```
ERROR: C:/users/pemgithub/_bazel_pemgithub/3mdmxsrc/external/gapic_third_party/BUILD.bazel:41:1: no such package '@org_lwjgl_core//jar': Failed to fetch Maven dependency: Could not transfer artifact org.lwjgl:lwjgl:jar:3.2.0 from/to org_lwjgl_core (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): connect timed out and referenced by '@gapic_third_party//:lwjgl'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:pkg' failed; build aborted: no such package '@org_lwjgl_core//jar': Failed to fetch Maven dependency: Could not transfer artifact org.lwjgl:lwjgl:jar:3.2.0 from/to org_lwjgl_core (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): connect timed out
INFO: Elapsed time: 11.858s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
    Fetching @com_github_pkg_errors; Restarting. 10s
```